# Android Edit a UI view from an AsyncTask

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask, textview

I have an `AsyncTask` extended class that listens to a port in the background.

My problem is that when I try to add the text that I receive from the socket into a `TextView` on the UI, the app stops because I'm doing it from outside of the activity thread. What do I need to do to my class to be able to edit the `TextView`?

Here is the code:

```
public class Receive_String extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {                  
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
            try {
            TextView text_ShowString=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_ShowString);

            ServerSocket conn = new ServerSocket(35316);            
            Socket listen=conn.accept();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(listen.getInputStream()));
            String message = input.readLine();

            text_Notificari.append(message);

            conn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}               
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do it in `onPostExecute`

Comment: Never Update `UI` from `doInBackground(....)` instead of Update in `onPostExecute(....)`

Comment: or in `onProgressUpdate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update in `onPostExecute()`. If you  continously reading from port and want to make changes in main UI do it in `onProgressUpdate()` .

Eg : Make text_ShowString and message global

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);    
    text_ShowString.setText(message);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it now!

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a) too

Answer (score 1):

Move your update-the-UI code to `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`.